# Search custom listview with database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, search, android-sqlite

Sorry for my English.
Please do not negative score!

I know how to search a ListView of the dynamic view ...
But I do not know how to search the database which feeds the ListView .

Can you tell me how to search the codes displayed in my ListView and get the values from the database?

this is my database class code:

```
    public DrLists findProduct(String Title) {
    String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + TABLE_NAME + " =  \"" + Title + "\"" ;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

drLists=new DrLists();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        drLists.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
        drLists.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        drLists.setFamily(cursor.getString(2));
        cursor.close();
    } else {
        drLists = null;
    }
    db.close();
    return drLists;
}
```

and this is my Activity code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.navigation);
    databaseAssets=new DatabaseAssets(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        databaseAssets.createDataBase();
        databaseAssets.openDataBase();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_search);
    Button search = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_search);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_drawerlayout);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.my_navigation);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
            drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();


    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             drLists=new DrLists();

            drLists=databaseAssets.findProduct(editText.getText().toString());

        }
    });
```

But `findProduct()` does not work!
What is the problem?

Comment: if you see `rawQuery` documentation you will see it has two parameters, read about the second one

Comment: Thank you for tips. But I do not understand what is TITLE_FIELD ?

Comment: what fields do you have in your `TABLE_NAME` ?

Comment: I named TITLE_FIELD the field which contains your Title, as in `WHERE yourFieldName='Some Title'`

Comment: So I must added another record in database table for TITLE_FIELD ?

Comment: how did you create your `TABLE_NAME` ? "CREATE TABLE ... " ?

Comment: NO. I suppose you already have a "title", where to search the Title value. Or else, I can't understand what are you trying to query. Your fields are? `_id`, `Name`, `Family`, and ... ??

Comment: my database Columns are: KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_FAMILY,I want to feel I'm one of them (KEY_NAME or  KEY_FAMILY)

Comment: So what is the TITLE value referred to? Name or Family? P.S.:, if you  don't prefix your comments with @UserName, noone will be notified. I don't need to, since you are the OP, so all comments are notified to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is the problem.
See what you are doing:

```
String query = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + TABLE_NAME + " =  \"" + Title + "\"" ;
```

Will be translated in SQL into something like

```
SELECT * FROM My_TABLE_NAME WHERE My_TABLE_NAME =  "Some Title"
```

You need to change it to something like

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + TITLE_FIELD + " =  '" + Title + "'" ;
```

---

Note: I couldn't be more precise, since I don't know the name of your table nor the name of your Title field.
Anyway, I do think it's pretty straightforward.

---

Note (2): Using **bound parameters**, as suggested by @pskink, would be a better option than using string delimiters.